# Set a Max allocated size for a sellected storage path in db2

Tags: db2, storage, ibm-data-studio

I have a DB2 storage group with storage paths set like

C:\

D:\

E:\

Size of my C: drive is 100 GB and the other programs keep crashing because it fill data drive by one, even I can allocate more storage and extend this it first fill free space 
In my c:\ drive and move to new storage, I like to know is it possible to give a max size for 1 particular drive(storage path) and how?

NOTE : If I can change the PathState to 'NotInUse' will it fix this , will it effect the editing of the existing data in that path ?

INFO: DB2 10.1

```
C:\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2pd -storagepaths -tablespaces -db DEMO

Database Member 0 -- Database DEMO -- Active -- Up 0 days 17:16:44 -- Date 02/09
/2016 11:06:24

Storage Group Configuration:
Address            SGID  Default  DataTag    Name
0x000007FFCCFCAE40 0     Yes      0          DEMOFORTEST

Storage Group Statistics:
Address            SGID  State      Numpaths  NumDropPen
0x000007FFCCFCAE40 0     0x00000000 2         0

Storage Group Paths:
Address            SGID  PathID    PathState    PathName
0x000007FFCCFF7560 0     0         InUse        C:
0x000007FFCCFCAF60 0     1         InUse        E:

Database Member 0 -- Database DEMO -- Active -- Up 0 days 17:16:44 -- Date 02/09
/2016 11:06:24

Tablespace Configuration:
Address            Id    Type Content PageSz ExtentSz Auto Prefetch BufID BufIDD
isk FSC NumCntrs MaxStripe  LastConsecPg Name
0x000007FFC0018BC0 0     DMS  Regular 32768  4        Yes  4        1     1
    Off 1        0          3            SYSCATSPACE
0x000007FFC0021460 1     SMS  SysTmp  32768  32       Yes  32       1     1
    On  1        0          31           TEMPSPACE1
0x000007FFC002C360 2     DMS  Large   32768  32       Yes  32       1     1
    Off 1        0          31           USERSPACE1
0x000007FFC0035360 3     DMS  Large   32768  4        Yes  4        1     1
    Off 1        0          3            SYSTOOLSPACE
0x000007FFC003E300 4     DMS  Regular 32768  16       No   16       1     1
    Off 2        1          15           STORE_TS
0x000007FFC0047480 5     DMS  Regular 32768  16       No   16       1     1
    Off 2        1          15           INDEX_TS
0x000007FFC0055B00 6     DMS  Large   32768  16       No   16       1     1
    Off 2        1          15           LOB_TS

Tablespace Statistics:
Address            Id    TotalPgs   UsablePgs  UsedPgs    PndFreePgs FreePgs
HWM        Max HWM    State      MinRecTime NQuiescers PathsDropped TrackmodStat
e
0x000007FFC0018BC0 0     7168       7164       6944       0          220
6944       6944       0x00000000 0          0          No           n/a

0x000007FFC0021460 1     1          1          1          0          0
0          0          0x00000000 0          0          No           n/a

0x000007FFC002C360 2     1024       992        96         0          896
96         96         0x00000000 0          0          No           n/a

0x000007FFC0035360 3     1024       1020       80         0          940
80         80         0x00000000 0          0          No           n/a

0x000007FFC003E300 4     1477648    1477616    1476624    0          992
1476624    1476624    0x00000000 0          0          No           n/a

0x000007FFC0047480 5     248832     248800     247792     0          1008
247792     247792     0x00000000 0          0          No           n/a

0x000007FFC0055B00 6     9134368    9134336    9134112    0          224
9134112    9134112    0x00000000 0          0          No           n/a


Tablespace Autoresize Statistics:
Address            Id    AS  AR  InitSize             IncSize              IIP M
axSize              LastResize                 LRF
0x000007FFC0018BC0 0     Yes Yes 33554432             -1                   No  N
one                 None                       No
0x000007FFC0021460 1     Yes No  0                    0                    No  0
                    None                       No
0x000007FFC002C360 2     Yes Yes 33554432             -1                   No  N
one                 None                       No
0x000007FFC0035360 3     Yes Yes 33554432             -1                   No  N
one                 None                       No
0x000007FFC003E300 4     Yes Yes 33554432             -1                   No  N
one                 02/09/2016 10:12:09.687557 No
0x000007FFC0047480 5     Yes Yes 33554432             -1                   No  N
one                 02/09/2016 10:52:17.557144 No
0x000007FFC0055B00 6     Yes Yes 33554432             -1                   No  N
one                 None                       No

Tablespace Storage Statistics:
Address            Id    DataTag  Rebalance SGID  SourceSGID
0x000007FFC0018BC0 0     0        No        0     -
0x000007FFC0021460 1     0        No        0     -
0x000007FFC002C360 2     -1       No        0     -
0x000007FFC0035360 3     -1       No        0     -
0x000007FFC003E300 4     -1       No        0     -
0x000007FFC0047480 5     -1       No        0     -
0x000007FFC0055B00 6     -1       No        0     -

Containers:
Address            TspId ContainNum Type    TotalPgs   UseablePgs PathID     Str
ipeSet  Container
0x000007FFC00558C0 0     0          File    7168       7164       0          0
        C:\DB2\NODE0000\DEMO\T0000000\C0000000.CAT
0x000007FFC002A080 1     0          Path    1          1          1          0
        E:\DB2\NODE0000\DEMO\T0000001\C0000000.TMP
0x000007FFC00350A0 2     0          File    1024       992        0          0
        C:\DB2\NODE0000\DEMO\T0000002\C0000000.LRG
0x000007FFC003E040 3     0          File    1024       1020       0          0
        C:\DB2\NODE0000\DEMO\T0000003\C0000000.LRG
0x000007FFC0047040 4     0          File    1303568    1303552    0          0
        C:\DB2\NODE0000\DEMO\T0000004\C0000000.USR
0x000007FFC0047250 4     1          File    174080     174064     1          1
        E:\DB2\NODE0000\DEMO\T0000004\C0000001.USR
0x000007FFC0050220 5     0          File    164864     164848     0          0
        C:\DB2\NODE0000\DEMO\T0000005\C0000000.USR
0x000007FFC0050430 5     1          File    83968      83952      1          1
        E:\DB2\NODE0000\DEMO\T0000005\C0000001.USR
0x000007FFC0050BE0 6     0          File    6504736    6504720    0          0
        C:\DB2\NODE0000\DEMO\T0000006\C0000000.LRG
0x000007FFC0050DF0 6     1          File    2629632    2629616    1          1
        E:\DB2\NODE0000\DEMO\T0000006\C0000001.LRG
```

Comment: Are you sure it's tablespace data that fills the C: drive? What DB2 version are you at? You may want to post the output of `db2pd -storagepaths -tablespaces`

Comment: @mustaccio I update the information

Comment: So, you do not have D: as a storage path, only C: and E:

Comment: @mustaccio , yes this is from a dump got early , Using this for testing before doing it with real database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers for tablespaces 4-6 seem seriously unbalanced, I guess the E: path was added recenty. One thing you could start with is rebalance them:

```
alter tablespace STORE_TS rebalance
```

etc.

You cannot control maximum size of a storage path, only a tablespace maximum size (which is calculated across all paths). If tablespace growth is causing harm on C: you should remove C: from the database storage paths altogether:

```
alter stogroup DEMOFORTEST drop 'C:'
```

Alternatively you can move the tablespaces that keep growing to a different, new storage group that does not use C:

Comment: yes E: path was added recently ,  if i drop storage group , will it effect the existing data(like editing them) . currently i am thinking of relocate the DB with new storage path , set containers to new location and remove all DB from C: . thanks for clarification in storage path.